Converting a 2nd order homogeneous equation into a known form of an Special function.
I got the following 2nd order fuchsian equation.
$z^2 u''(z)+z u'(z)+\left(\frac{A \beta }{(z-1)^2}+\frac{A (\alpha +\beta )}{z-1}-A
   E\right)u(z)=0$
I am pretty impressed by how close it looks to the
Double Confluent Heun equation:
$z^2 u''(z) + z u'(z) + \left(-\frac{k^2}{z^2}+ \frac{D}{z}- L^2+ Bz -k^2z^2   \right)u(z) =0$
But with the subtle and apalling fact that instead of $z$ as denominator it has $z-1$.
I wonder if it would be possible to try to convert it into either a suitable form of any Special function such a Heun equation or Hypergeometric (Which should be achievable since it is fuchsian), or another possibility is that this is a case of other known type of equations, which I'm not aware of.
By the way, I would appreciate any comment or idea in case you have had to deal with something like this before or in case you recognize this equation from somewhere.
